# can we create a view using SUM or AVG depends on a condition?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, functions, aggregate

I want to get the **same result** even if I add a column in the **GROUP BY** section or not for this case : 
The table contains sale_id,product_id, command quantity and delivered quantity 
I want to get sum of sale quantity if the grouping by product_id data

```
CREATE TABLE sales ( id serial unique ,group_id INTEGER ); 
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(3063,500);

CREATE TABLE sale_lines ( id serial unique , sale_id INTEGER, product_id INTEGER, sale_qty Float ); 
INSERT INTO sale_lines VALUES
  (106827,3063,3135,1100.000),
  (107827,3063,3145,1100.000),
  (118828,3063,3155,400.000);

CREATE TABLE pickings ( id serial unique ,group_id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO pickings VALUES
  (55,500),
  (56,500),
  (57,500); 

CREATE TABLE picking_lines
( id serial unique ,  product_id INTEGER, picking_id INTEGER, delivered_qty Float ); 
INSERT INTO picking_lines VALUES
  (10,3135,55,300.000),
  (11,3145,55,500.000),
  (12,3155,55,100.000),

  (20,3135,56,700.000),
  (21,3145,56,100.000),
  (22,3155,56,200.000),

  (30,3135,57,100.000),
  (31,3145,57,500.000),
  (32,3155,57,100.000);
```

here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    --sl.product_id,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty)/count(sl.product_id) sale_qty,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty) sum_sale_qty,
    sum( pl.delivered_qty) delivered_qty
FROM sale_lines sl left join sales s on s.id = sl.sale_id 
LEFT JOIN pickings p on p.group_id = s.group_id 
LEFT JOIN picking_lines pl ON pl.picking_id = p.id
WHERE sl.product_id=pl.product_id
GROUP BY s.id 
       --,sl.product_id
;
```

Which produces

```
  id  |     sale_qty     | sum_sale_qty | delivered_qty 
------+------------------+--------------+---------------
 3063 | 866.666666666667 |         7800 |          2600
```

I want to get **the same result** of sale_qty for the two cases: 
1) using `GROUP BY sale_id, sl.product_id`
 
2) just using `GROUP BY s.id`

I want to get the result **with and without grouping** on **sl.product_id**

```
  id  |     sale_qty     | delivered_qty 
------+------------------+---------------
 3063 |           2600   |          2600
```

here is the link of the query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5ac2/1

Comment: `the result wanted after commenting the last line` or `uncommenting` the last line. You're confusing me with your use of comment and uncommenting. The last line in your example is commented. Are you uncommenting it or doing something different?

Comment: My suggesting is to rewrite it and be explicit don't use comments in SQL just ask the question and show us what you want.

Comment: @EvanCarroll as far as I understand, sale_qty should sum 2600 instead of 866.6, probably `/count(sl.product_id)` is not correct.

Comment: ok, could you try to explain what should this returns: `SUM( sl.sale_qty)/count(sl.product_id) sale_qty` because `400+1100+1100=2600` you don't need to divide by count(product_id)

Comment: @McNets I just want to get the sum(sale_qty) = 2600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get aggregated sales by product**

```
select    s.id,
          sl.product_id,
          sum(sl.sale_qty) sum_sale_qty
from      sale_lines sl 
left join sales s
on        s.id = sl.sale_id
group by  s.id, sl.product_id;
```

This returns next values:

```
| id   | product_id | sum_sale_qty |
|------|-----------:|-------------:|
| 3063 |       3135 |         1100 |
| 3063 |       3145 |         1100 |
| 3063 |       3155 |          400 |
```

**Get aggregated delivered by products**

```
select    pl.product_id,
          sum(delivered_qty) sum_dlv_qty
from      pickings p
left join picking_lines pl
on        p.id = pl.picking_id       
group by  pl.product_id;
```

And this returns:

```
| product_id | sum_dlv_qty |
|------------|------------:|
| 3145       |        1100 |
| 3135       |        1100 |
| 3155       |         400 |
```

Now, try to join it by product_id, and get the aggregate by id:

```
select    s.id,
          sum(sl.sale_qty) sum_sale_qty,
          sum(pk.dlv_qty) sum_dlv_qty
from      sale_lines sl 
left join sales s
on        s.id = sl.sale_id
left join (select    pl.product_id,
                     sum(delivered_qty) dlv_qty
           from      pickings p
           left join picking_lines pl
           on        p.id = pl.picking_id       
           group by  pl.product_id
          ) pk
on        pk.product_id = sl.product_id 
group by  s.id;

|   id | sum_sale_qty | sum_dlv_qty |
|-----:|-------------:|------------:|
| 3063 |         2600 |        2600 |
```

Comment: can I display p.id and get the same result ?

Comment: p.id and s.id is the same value

Comment: p.id  is pl.picking_id

Comment: @m3asmi: If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question, thank you.

Comment: @AndriyM it's the same problem, I just want to display more fields

Comment: @m3asmi the problem is that we don't understand exactly what you want. please try to redefine your question and show your final desired result.

Comment: @m3asmi: Apart from what McNets said, it's also confusing. You've accepted this answer, which effectively translates to "My problem has been resolved", and yet you are asking more questions as though the problem is still there. If the original problem is resolved but you have further questions, please ask them in a new post (or posts). Feel free to add a link to this question if that may provide useful context in your opinion.

Comment: thanks for your reaction, I guess it will be impossible to get what I want in the same question, I will create a new post covering what I want

Comment: @AndriyM the two  solution of RMathis and Mcnet are the solution  for this question

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the introduction of a Cartesian product when joining to the pickings table.  This can be eliminated by summarizing the sale and delivery as derived tables which are then joined together.

```
 select q1.id,
        sum(q1.sale_qty) as sale_qty,
        sum(q2.delivered_qty) as delivered_qty
   from ( select s.id,
                 s.group_id,
                 sl.product_id,
                 sum(sl.sale_qty) as sale_qty
           from sales s
           join sale_lines sl on (sl.sale_id=s.id)
          group by s.id
                 , sl.product_id) as q1,
        ( select p.group_id,
                 pl.product_id,
                 sum(pl.delivered_qty) as delivered_qty
            from pickings p
            join picking_lines pl on (pl.picking_id=p.id)
           group by group_id,
                    product_id) as q2
  where q2.group_id=q1.group_id
    and q2.product_id=q1.product_id
  group by q1.id;
 +------+----------+---------------+
 | id   | sale_qty | delivered_qty |
 +------+----------+---------------+
 | 3063 |     2600 |          2600 |
 +------+----------+---------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Giving it a bit more thought, I doubt you need to group the first derived table. (And if you don't need to group those rows, you don't need that derived table either, you can join the underlying tables in the main query instead.) It seems unlikely, even though not explicitly stated in the original post, that there can be multiple identical product IDs per `(sale_id, group_id)`. Although `sales_lines` does have its own ID, it's likely just a surrogate key, and the actual (natural) key is likely `(sales_id, group_id, product_id)`. That's my estimation anyway, YMMV.

Comment: @RMathis can I display `pl.picking_id` and get the same result ?

Comment: this will reintroduce the Cartesian - each group will be duplicated by each picking_id
     +------+------------+----------+---------------+<br/>
     | id   | picking_id | sale_qty | delivered_qty |<br/>
    +------+------------+----------+---------------+<br/>
     | 3063 |         55 |     2600 |           900 |<br/>
     | 3063 |         56 |     2600 |          1000 |<br/>
     | 3063 |         57 |     2600 |           700 |<br/>
     +------+------------+----------+---------------+<br/>
     3 rows in set (0.00 sec)<br/>

Answer (score 2):

## Reading of problem

I'm not sure I understand this question still.. If you uncomment out those lines and group by product id you get this..

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    sl.product_id,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty)/count(sl.product_id) sale_qty,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty) sum_sale_qty,
    sum( pl.delivered_qty) delivered_qty
FROM sale_lines sl left join sales s on s.id = sl.sale_id 
LEFT JOIN pickings p on p.group_id = s.group_id 
LEFT JOIN picking_lines pl ON pl.picking_id = p.id
WHERE sl.product_id=pl.product_id
GROUP BY s.id 
       ,sl.product_id
; 
  id  | product_id | sale_qty | sum_sale_qty | delivered_qty 
------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------
 3063 |       3155 |      400 |         1200 |           400
 3063 |       3145 |     1100 |         3300 |          1100
 3063 |       3135 |     1100 |         3300 |          1100
```

You've already got this.

```
  id  |     sale_qty     | sum_sale_qty | delivered_qty 
------+------------------+--------------+---------------
 3063 | 866.666666666667 |         7800 |          2600
```

I'm assuming your problem is sale_qty is 866.66, and you want it to be the sum of the others. Currently you're calculating it like this

```
    SUM( sl.sale_qty)/count(sl.product_id) sale_qty,
```

Let's go back to your original query.. and break that apart

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    --sl.product_id,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty) AS numerator,
    count(sl.product_id) AS denominator,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty) sum_sale_qty,
    sum( pl.delivered_qty) delivered_qty
FROM sale_lines sl left join sales s on s.id = sl.sale_id 
LEFT JOIN pickings p on p.group_id = s.group_id 
LEFT JOIN picking_lines pl ON pl.picking_id = p.id
WHERE sl.product_id=pl.product_id
GROUP BY s.id 
       --,sl.product_id
;

  id  | numerator | denominator | sum_sale_qty | delivered_qty 
------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------
 3063 |      7800 |           9 |         7800 |          2600
(1 row)
```

You can see here you're dividing the 7800 by 9 to get the 866.66. Because I'm operating off of the idea that you want 2600, I assume that I need to solve for `x` in `7800/x=2600`, and then I need to figure out how you indended to generate `x`. So in the above x=3 to get 2600.

## Probable solution

That's presumably because you have three product groups.. so I think what you want is `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty)/count(DISTINCT sl.product_id) sale_qty,
    SUM( sl.sale_qty) sum_sale_qty,
    sum( pl.delivered_qty) delivered_qty
FROM sale_lines sl left join sales s on s.id = sl.sale_id
LEFT JOIN pickings p on p.group_id = s.group_id
LEFT JOIN picking_lines pl ON pl.picking_id = p.id
WHERE sl.product_id=pl.product_id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Again, I think it is stretch but it seems reasonable that this is what you're looking for. `count(product_id)` counts all product ids, not just the distinct ones.

Comment: that's good, but in the query if you add  group by sl.product_id you'll get false result in the sale_qty :/

Comment: You said in the question **I want to get the result without grouping on sl.product_id** it's even in bold. Do you want to group by product_id, or not?

Comment: @m3asmi it works, check it [here](http://rextester.com/QOM53885)

Comment: @EvanCarroll I want to get the result **with and without groupping on sl.product_id**

Comment: @m3asmi I again then don't know what you're asking for.. You want two different queries that generate two different results? I asked you what you wanted, you showed me what you wanted and I gave you the query to generate it. What more do you want?

Comment: If you group by different things.. it stands to reason you're going to need a different query, and you're going to generate a different output.

Comment: @EvanCarroll thanks for your reaction, I didn't explain well what I want, I want to get the same result of sale_qty for the two cases 1) using group by sale_id and sl.product_id 2) just using group by sale_id